# How to present One to Many relationship in Spring MVC JSP form

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jstl

I have problem with presenting One to many relationship in JSP form using spring MVC. Bellow i am giving 3 files. Here one to many Relationship between Student and mark. So at the time of adding and updating of student details How can i represent Mark set in JSP. Actually what i wrote in jsp page i.e not working. Another thing i want a single object in controller at form submit.

**Student.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="net.startMVC.pojo.Student" table="student" catalog="spring_mvc_start" >
    <id name="studid" type="int" >
        <column name="studid" />
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="address" class="net.startMVC.pojo.Address" lazy="false"  fetch="select">
        <column name="addressid" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" length="100" />
    </property>
    <property name="roleNo" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="role_no" />
    </property>
    <property name="stream" type="string">
        <column name="stream" length="50" />
    </property>
    <list name="marks" table="mark" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="studid" />
        </key>
         <list-index base="1" column="markid"/>
        <one-to-many class="net.startMVC.pojo.Mark" />
    </list>
</class>
```

**Mark.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="net.startMVC.pojo.Mark" table="mark" catalog="spring_mvc_start">
    <id name="markid" type="int">
        <column name="markid" />
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="student" class="net.startMVC.pojo.Student" fetch="select">
        <column name="studid" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="totalMark" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="total_mark" />
    </property>
</class>
```

**Add controller method**

```
@RequestMapping("/addStudent")
public ModelAndView addStudent(Model model)
{
    System.out.println("comming controller");
    return new ModelAndView("addStudent", "command", new Student());
}
```

**Edit controller method**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/editStudent", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editStudent(@RequestParam String studID,Model model)
{
    System.out.println("studID->"+studID);
    setStudent(helloMVCService.getOneStudentDetails(studID));
    return new ModelAndView("addStudent", "command", getStudent());
}
```

**Save and Update controller method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addNewStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute Student student,Model model) {
  helloMVCService.saveStudentData(student);      
  return "redirect:/hello";
}
```

**addStudend.jsp**

```
<form:form method="POST" action="addNewStudent">
<form:hidden path="studid"/>
<table>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="roleNo">Roll No</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="roleNo" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="stream">Stream</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="stream" /></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td><form:label path="address.loc">Location</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="address.loc" /></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form:label path="address.state">State</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="address.state" /></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td><form:label path="address.country">Country</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="address.country" /></td>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="marks" varStatus="vs" items="${marks}">
<tr>
    <td><form:label path="marks[vs.index].totalMark">Mark</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="marks[vs.index].totalMark" /></td>
</tr> 
</c:forEach>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
```

Comment: What problem do you face? Also post the controller method where you make call to this jsp.

Comment: controller method                                         @RequestMapping("/addStudent")
 public ModelAndView addStudent(Model model)
 {
  System.out.println("comming controller");
  return new ModelAndView("addStudent", "command", new Student());
 }   At the time of adding new student how can i represent marks set in jsp page. Actually what i wrote in jsp page i.e not working. And also edit time how can i represent marks set in jsp. Another thing i want a single object when i submit the data.